# loading custom nodes and edges with graphml and jung

Tags: java, graph, bigdata, jung, graphml

I'm confronted with problems while I#m trying to read and write graphs from and to a text file with JUNG. The situation is as follows: Given is a file that contains coordinates of a multigraph and its weight.

An example is:

```
6346    6728    5911    156 5
6346    6728    6599    156 10
6346    6728    8555    156 5
```

I have written a converter with JUNG that reads a file that contains millions of such rows and constructs a

```
DirectedSparseMultigraph<Node, Edge>
```

Nodes and Edges are custom made classes listed below

```
class Node {
    int id; // good coding practice would have this as private

    public Node(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String toString() { // Always a good idea for debuging
        return "V"+id;
   // JUNG2 makes good use of these.
    }        
}

class Edge { 
    Context context;  
    Time time;
    Value value;
    int id;
    public Edge(int id, Context context, Time time, Value value) {
        this.id = id; // This is defined in the outer class.
        this.context = context;
        this.time = time;
        this.value = value;
    } 
    public String toString() { // Always good for debugging
        return "E"+id;
    }
}
```

Constructing a graph in memory from this data works fine. We come closer to the problem. It is important to note that **saving the constructed graph to disk works fine** by using a method save() of the 
 DirectedSparseMultigraph object. In a next step, the constructed DirectedSparseMultigraph is loaded from disk by the following lines of code

```
    GraphMLReader<DirectedSparseMultigraph<Node, Edge>, Node, Edge> gmlr = null;

    try
    {
        gmlr = new GraphMLReader<DirectedSparseMultigraph<Node, Edge>, Node, Edge>();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    DirectedSparseMultigraph<Node, Edge> g_new = null;
    try
    {
        gmlr.load("bla.sh", g_new);
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And that is where the problem starts. The error message is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: If no edge factory is supplied, edge id may not be null: {source=V6818, target=V2472}
at edu.uci.ics.jung.io.GraphMLReader.createEdge(GraphMLReader.java:693)
at edu.uci.ics.jung.io.GraphMLReader.startElement(GraphMLReader.java:299)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1343)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2786)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:333)
at edu.uci.ics.jung.io.GraphMLReader.parse(GraphMLReader.java:241)
at edu.uci.ics.jung.io.GraphMLReader.load(GraphMLReader.java:192)
at edu.uci.ics.jung.io.GraphMLReader.load(GraphMLReader.java:201)
at main.Graph.main(Graph.java:99)
```

If you have any Ideas or hints how this problem can be solved, I really look forward to your message.
greetings
J Bug

Comment: A quick stab at this: You have to use the `GraphMLReader` constructor that receives a `Factory<V>` for the vertices and a `Factory<E>` for the edges, and thes factories should create instances of your `Vertex`- and `Edge` classes, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways for GraphMLReader to be able to parse your file:

(1) You supply node and edge factories; in this case your node and edge types can be anything you want.  ([constructor with factories](http://jrtom.github.io/jung/javadoc/edu/uci/ics/jung/io/GraphMLReader.html#GraphMLReader-com.google.common.base.Supplier-com.google.common.base.Supplier-))

(2) You don't supply node and edge factories; in this case your node and edge types must be `String`s.  ([constructor without factories](http://jrtom.github.io/jung/javadoc/edu/uci/ics/jung/io/GraphMLReader.html#GraphMLReader--))

Your code doesn't supply node and edge factories, and your `Edge` type is not assignment-compatible with `String`, so it blows up.  Admittedly this is not super-obvious from the error message, but it's fairly clear in [the code](https://github.com/jrtom/jung/blob/master/jung-io/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/jung/io/GraphMLReader.java#L698).

In this case you can't really provide `Node` and `Edge` factories (without redesigning them), because you don't have a no-arg constructor.  So you'd either need to redesign those classes, or use a two-stage process, i.e.: parse the graph using simple String keys for the nodes and edges + populate the metadata, and then build a new graph based on the data structures that GraphMLReader provides.

Comment: Thank you for helping me and let me apologize for accepting the answer that late but i wanted to provide also a concrete solution that may help others in similar situations. Therefore i came across https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063810/saving-jung-graph-with-custom-node-and-edge where an example is provided that goes along with your advice. It is a bit clumsy but after one get used to it, it works perfectly and can be extended easily. thank you again.

Comment: according to this one can check http://www.eyeshalfclosed.com/blog/2010/12/04/graphml-with-jung-loading-from-graphml/ as well